# “/etc/hosts” hostnames ignored and searched instead in Safari and Chrome

Tags: macos, browser, vagrant, hosts-file

I added the local url data `192.168.33.11 core-fine.local` into `/etc/hosts`, saved the file and for a time I was able to serve and see a local website powered by Vagrant.

It was all working just fine until suddenly whenever I typed or pasted the URL, *core-fine.local* or even the IP address, both Safari and Chrome would search Google for that text rather than serve my website.

I had am trying `http://core-fine.local` as well but that was still being searched.

Comment: Have you tried `http://core-fine.local` or `https://core-fine.local`?

Comment: I had been trying `http://core-fine.local` but that was still being searched. I just tried with https and that did not get searched. I don't recall setting any SSL https settings

Answer (score 0):

## This is normal and expected behavior.

Unless you explicitly specify the URL scheme and prepend `http://` to the hostname:

```
http://core-fine.local
```

Or even `https://`:

```
https://core-fine.local
```

Safari and Chrome will interpret a pure hostname like `core-fine.local` as simply a search word in the omnibar.

Comment: However, I always specified `http://core-fine.local`. Shouldn't that indicate a site rather than a search parameter ? AND, it was working until recently.